# jQuery Event Delegation with QL Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an onclick event using jquery where I'm populating a modal with the text/html of a particular announcement that has been clicked to edit. I'm able to use my knowledge of event delegation to populate the modal with populate all but one fields of the modal form with the appropriate text from the DOM, but I'm not able to pin down what the path is to grab the html value and populate the text editor (i'm using quillJS) of the modal. here is my onclick event code where I'm able to grab the title, call to action button, call to action link, and order:

```js
$('.card-test').on('click', '.edit-btn', function () {
    id = $(this).data('property');
    $('#titleEdit').val($(this).parent().find('.card-title').text());
    $('#ctaTitleEdit').val($(this).parent().find('#ctaText').text());
    $('#ctaLinkEdit').val($(this).parent().find('#ctaURL').attr('href'));
    $(`#orderNumberEdit`).val($(this).parent().find('#orderNumberSpan').text())
})
```

Here's the HTML of the announcement with the information that populates the modal:

```html
<div class="card-test row">
    <div class="container py-3">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="" class="w-100">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 px-3">
                <div class="card-block px-3">
                    <h5 class="card-title mc-title pt-3">Test Announcement</h5>
                    <div class="card-text" id="descriptionBodyHTML"><p>body... click <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">here</a>.</p></div>
                    <a id="ctaURL" href="https://google.com"><div id="ctaText" class="btn btn-success mb-2" data-property="5c4e13f8aeb84c29ec17fc9a">Click Here</div></a>
                    <br><br>
                    <p class="card-text">Order:</p>
                    <p class="card-text" id="orderNumberSpan">10</p>
                    <div data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary edit-btn mb-2" data-property="5c4e13f8aeb84c29ec17fc9a" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit</div>
                 <div class="btn btn-danger mb-2 delete-btn" data-dbid="5c4e13f8aeb84c29ec17fc9a"><i class="fa fa-trash-o pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

And here is the html of the modal when it's open:

```html
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title mc-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Announcement</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="/api/announcements" method="post">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control mb-2 mc-title" id="titleEdit" name="title">
            <label>Description</label>
            <div class="ql-toolbar ql-snow"><span class="ql-formats"><span class="ql-header ql-picker"><span class="ql-picker-label" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ql-picker-options-1"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <polygon class="ql-stroke" points="7 11 9 13 11 11 7 11"></polygon> <polygon class="ql-stroke" points="7 7 9 5 11 7 7 7"></polygon> </svg></span><span class="ql-picker-options" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" id="ql-picker-options-1"><span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="1"></span><span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="2"></span><span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item" data-value="3"></span><span tabindex="0" role="button" class="ql-picker-item ql-selected"></span></span></span><select class="ql-header" style="display: none;"><option value="1"></option><option value="2"></option><option value="3"></option><option selected="selected"></option></select></span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-bold"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,4H9.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,12,6.5v0A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,9.5,9H5A0,0,0,0,1,5,9V4A0,0,0,0,1,5,4Z"></path> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,9h5.5A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,13,11.5v0A2.5,2.5,0,0,1,10.5,14H5a0,0,0,0,1,0,0V9A0,0,0,0,1,5,9Z"></path> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-italic"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="13" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="5" x2="11" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="8" x2="10" y1="14" y2="4"></line> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-underline"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <path class="ql-stroke" d="M5,3V9a4.012,4.012,0,0,0,4,4H9a4.012,4.012,0,0,0,4-4V3"></path> <rect class="ql-fill" height="1" rx="0.5" ry="0.5" width="12" x="3" y="15"></rect> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-link"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="11" y1="7" y2="11"></line> <path class="ql-even ql-stroke" d="M8.9,4.577a3.476,3.476,0,0,1,.36,4.679A3.476,3.476,0,0,1,4.577,8.9C3.185,7.5,2.035,6.4,4.217,4.217S7.5,3.185,8.9,4.577Z"></path> <path class="ql-even ql-stroke" d="M13.423,9.1a3.476,3.476,0,0,0-4.679-.36,3.476,3.476,0,0,0,.36,4.679c1.392,1.392,2.5,2.542,4.679.36S14.815,10.5,13.423,9.1Z"></path> </svg></button></span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-list" value="ordered"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="7" x2="15" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke ql-thin" x1="2.5" x2="4.5" y1="5.5" y2="5.5"></line> <path class="ql-fill" d="M3.5,6A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,3,5.5V3.085l-0.276.138A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,2.053,3c-0.124-.247-0.023-0.324.224-0.447l1-.5A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,4,2.5v3A0.5,0.5,0,0,1,3.5,6Z"></path> <path class="ql-stroke ql-thin" d="M4.5,10.5h-2c0-.234,1.85-1.076,1.85-2.234A0.959,0.959,0,0,0,2.5,8.156"></path> <path class="ql-stroke ql-thin" d="M2.5,14.846a0.959,0.959,0,0,0,1.85-.109A0.7,0.7,0,0,0,3.75,14a0.688,0.688,0,0,0,.6-0.736,0.959,0.959,0,0,0-1.85-.109"></path> </svg></button><button type="button" class="ql-list" value="bullet"><svg viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="15" y1="14" y2="14"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="4" y2="4"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="9" y2="9"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="3" x2="3" y1="14" y2="14"></line> </svg></button></span><span class="ql-formats"><button type="button" class="ql-clean"><svg class="" viewBox="0 0 18 18"> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="5" x2="13" y1="3" y2="3"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="6" x2="9.35" y1="12" y2="3"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="11" x2="15" y1="11" y2="15"></line> <line class="ql-stroke" x1="15" x2="11" y1="11" y2="15"></line> <rect class="ql-fill" height="1" rx="0.5" ry="0.5" width="7" x="2" y="14"></rect> </svg></button></span></div><div placeholder="Description" class="form-control mb-2 ql-container ql-snow" name="description" id="descriptionEdit"><div class="ql-editor ql-blank" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true"><p><br></p></div><div class="ql-clipboard" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1"></div><div class="ql-tooltip ql-hidden"><a class="ql-preview" target="_blank" href="about:blank"></a><input type="text" data-formula="e=mc^2" data-link="https://quilljs.com" data-video="Embed URL"><a class="ql-action"></a><a class="ql-remove"></a></div></div>
            <label>Call to Action Button</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Call to Action" class="form-control mb-2 mc-title" id="ctaTitleEdit" name="ctaTitle">
            <label>Call to Action Link</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Call to Action Link" class="form-control mb-2 mc-title" id="ctaLinkEdit" name="ctaLink">
            <label>Order</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Number" id="orderNumberEdit" name="order">
            <button class="btn btn-mc mt-2 form-control update-put-btn">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>Ï
```

My goal is to populate the `<p>` tag inside the `<div class="ql-editor ql-blank" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true"><p><br></p></div>`. What would the jQuery selector be? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no element with the class `card-test` in your code. Did you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: Yes there was. I now corrected it.

Comment: I find that if I use the selector `$('#descriptionEdit > div.ql-editor.ql-blank').html('test')` i can populate the right element, but i'm not able to select the `'#descriptionBodyHTML'` element's HTML...

Comment: My suspicions are that the modal's HTML is not accessible the moment when the click event on the button is fired. In other words, when the logic in the click event handler is being executed, all the elements referenced are still not present in the DOM (probably because the modal takes time to render). What happens if you wrap all the DOM-accessing logic in a `window.setTimeout()`, does it work?

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. thanks for the help!